# How to set relaxedQueryChars of tomcat from the application level

Tags: java, tomcat

Allowing special characters in request URL is possible in tomcat_folder/conf/server.xml as far as I know, but I am somewhat required to find another way to set these special characters from the application side (if it is possible), I mean using web.xml or any other way. Here, I have enabled "[" (opening square bracket) and "]" (closing square bracket) in the query:

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" relaxedQueryChars='|[]'
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

This works pretty fine and I would appreciate it if anyone can help me to set without touching server.xml.

Info about the application environment:
**Tomcat version: 7.0.96,
Spring: 4.1.7.RELEASE**

Comment: You cannot change the server configuration from a single application. Imagine 100 application running and each modofying the carefully crafted `server.xml`... And if you could you should'nt as this configuration effects **ALL** the applications running in tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **@M.Deinum**.

*It is not recommended to touch `server.xml` of the tomcat using java code as it can stop other application from working properly.*

**But still you want to do, you can take the risk.**

Sample Java code :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class RelaxedQueryCharsExample {

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, TransformerException {

        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        File file = new File("D:/tomcat/conf/server.xml");
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse(file);
        NodeList list = document.getElementsByTagName("Connector");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = list.item(i);
            NamedNodeMap map = node.getAttributes();
            if (map.getNamedItem("port").getNodeValue().equalsIgnoreCase("8080") 
      && map.getNamedItem("protocol").getNodeValue().equalsIgnoreCase("HTTP/1.1")) {
                map.getNamedItem("relaxedQueryChars").setNodeValue("|[]");
            }

        }

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        document.setXmlStandalone(true);
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
        transformer.transform(source,result);
    }

}
```

**Note:** Run this code before running tomcat server. In between running this may crash the server.